# How to run a terminal command from grunt task function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to move some icons in my app directory based on a function i have inside my `Gruntfile.js`. Would it be possible to do something like this? I've tried the following (going into dev or staging folder and copying all files to the previous directory), but coudn't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
grunt.registerTask('setAppIcon', 'Task that sets the app icon', function(environment) {
        if (environment.toLowerCase() == "development") {

            grunt.task.run(['exec:command:cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/dev && cp -a . ../']);

        } else if (environment.toLowerCase() == "staging") {

            grunt.task.run(['exec:command:cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/staging && cp -a . ../']);

        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I ended up using [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs).

All i had to do was go to my app's root directory, run the following shell command to install it with npm : `npm install -g shelljs` and modify my script to look something like this

```
// Script to have environment specific icon
    grunt.registerTask('setAppIcon', 'Task that sets the app icon', function() {
        var env = grunt.option('env');
        var shell = require('shelljs');
    if (env.toLowerCase() === "development") {

        shell.exec('cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/dev && cp -a . ../');

    } else if (env.toLowerCase() === "staging") {

        shell.exec('cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/staging && cp -a . ../');

    } else if (env.toLowerCase() === "production") {

        shell.exec('cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/prod && cp -a . ../');
    }
});
```